# Nextcloud/Collabora: Set Nickname automatically

Tags: nextcloud

When editing a document anonymously in Nextcloud/Collabora, you are asked:

```
Please choose your nickname to continue as guest user.
```

Can I add something to the URL, which will skip this step?

Maybe something like: https://cloud/s/documentid?nickname=undef